# Fixing Load-Hit-Store

Tags: c++

How would the LHS be fixed in [this code](http://macton.smugmug.com/gallery/8936708_T6zQX/1/593426709_ZX4pZ#!i=593420229&k=v7zei)?

First, where does the LHS occur? I'm guessing it's in the `else if` by reading `s.r` a second time.

From what I've been reading about LHS I believe that adding a local would fix it:

```
float radius = s.r;

if( d <= -radius )
    ...
else if( d >= radius)
    ...
```

But since <= is a function what prevents <= or any other function that takes the local as a reference from modifying it?

Comment: If you're doing this to increase performance, you've already dived about 17 levels too deep into subtle hardware details.

Comment: @Mysticial This is mostly for educational purposes, I don't plan to do this kind of optimization at this point, but would like to know how it works...

Comment: If you're really interested in it. The first thing you might want to do is to redo this in assembly. The compiler can really deface that code simply by promoting `radius` into a register.

Comment: I really don't see the LHS mentioned. There is no possibility of a write access to `s.r` between the two accesses, so there is no reason to reload `s.r`. So I would think that it doesn't acutally contain an LHS. @Mysticial: Generally speaking that this kind of optimization seems perfectly normal to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't, look at [the next slide](http://macton.smugmug.com/gallery/8936708_T6zQX/1/593426709_ZX4pZ#!i=607382246&k=uJbp4).  It causes a pipeline flush.  There's also a good chance there will be a branch misprediction.